# How to write divided by in objective function

Tags: optimization, opl

My problem is multi-objective optimization problem. The expression for the objective function is given below:

Maximize (w1*F1 + w2*(1/F2))

w1 and w2 are weighting of two objective function F1 and (1/F2)

I want to write the code in OPL CPLEX.

So if I am writing the objective function as - Maximize (w1*F1 + w2*(1/F2))

The error that I am getting in OPL Cplex is - CPLEX(default) cannot extract expression: 1 / F2

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to use CP within CPLEX as can be seen at https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zoononlinear.mod

```
using CP;

// CPOptimizer allows all kind of non linearities

int nbKids=300;
float costBus40=500;
float costBus30=400;
 
dvar int+ nbBus40;
dvar int+ nbBus30;
 
// Non linear objective (exponential) 
minimize
 costBus40*exp(nbBus40) +exp(nbBus30)*costBus30;
 
subject to
{
 40*nbBus40+nbBus30*30>=nbKids;
}
```

If I change this to use 1/x , I can write

```
using CP;

// CPOptimizer allows all kind of non linearities

int nbKids=300;
float costBus40=500;
float costBus30=400;
dvar int+ nbBus40 in 1..10;
dvar int+ nbBus30 in 1..10;
 

minimize
 costBus40/nbBus40 +costBus30/nbBus30;
 
subject to
{
 40*nbBus40+nbBus30*30>=nbKids;
}
```

Comment: I am not able to write 1 divided by F2 in Cplex. How do I write this in OPL cplex.

Comment: these are some decision variables of my problem --                                                        dvar float+ qd[Node];
dvar float+ pg[Node];                                                                                                     The error I am getting with these variables after writing [using CP]; - Decision variables of type dvar float+ not supported by this algorithm.

Comment: You can turn your float variables into float decision expressions. See https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zoodecimalcpo.mod

Comment: int scale=1;                                                                                                                         int num_lines = 74;                                                                                                           range Line = 1..num_lines;   dvar int+ P_pf[Line];    float pf[Line] = P_pf[Line]/scale;                 The error with above code is -Cannot use type range for int.

Comment: Can you open a new question since this is not any more about dividing with a decision variable ?